# ¿Cómo mostrar datos de campos personalizados en wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo varios campos personalizados para los post en wordpress. Los he creado con el plugin Advanced Custom Fields. Los valores para los campos son enviados desde un formulario que yo he creado y, hasta el momento, guarda los datos después de insertar el post pero cuando veo la entrada en la web no puedo visualizar los datos. Si ingreso al post por medio del dashboard los datos aparecen y hasta que actualizo el post desde el dashboard en la web ya se muestran los datos de los campos.
Aquí mi código.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_title' => 'Titulo de entrada',
    'post_content' => 'Contenido de prueba',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_category' => array(1),
    'comment_status' => 'closed', 
    'ping_status' => 'closed'
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($args);

//Campos personalizados
update_field('nombre_del_equipo', $nombre_equipo, $post_id );
```

Parte de código del single.php aquí muestro los campos personalizados en el detalle de la entrada.

```
<?php 
    the_content();
    echo get_field('nombre_del_equipo');
?>
```

La documentación del plugin indica que de esa manera se muestran los campos.

Answer (score 2):

La mejor manera para mostrar datos con advanced custom field es remplazar el `get_field($custom)` con `the_field($custom, $idpost);` así nos ahorramos el `echo`, ahora bien, los dos necesitan dos parametros para funcionar correctamente, en este caso debes de agregar el ID del post para que advanced custom fields pueda buscar los campos del ID correcto.

Cambia la línea :

`echo get_field('nombre_del_equipo');` por `the_field('nombre_del_equipo', get_the_ID());`

`get_the_ID()` es una función de Wordpress que devuelve el ID del post actual.

Intentalo y me cuentas :)